# TypeError: 'A' object is not callable

Tags: python

What is happening here?

What do the brackets do here `test2 = A()`?

How can I make object A() callable.

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def a(self):
        "an important attribute"
        return ["a value","dsfsdfsd"]

test1 = A

test2 = A()


print test1().a                                

print test2().a
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: `A` is already callable, `A()` is not. What are you asking for?

Comment: `test2` is an object which is an instance of the `A` class. Instances of a class are not callable unless the `__call__()` method has been defined in the class definition. Classes _are_ callable by default and they create, intialize, and return instance objects of the class when they are called.

Comment: @martineau slight nit-pick - they return an object - it needn't be of the same class etc... etc...

Comment: Test1 is not an  instance of the A class?

Comment: Those "brackets" are commonly called parentheses.

Comment: @Dave: Correct. `test1` _is_ the `A` class

Comment: @Jon Clements: I don't think we're in a good situation to bring up the nuance you mention...

Comment: The parentheses after the `A` cause the class to be called which usually will return with class instance object. If an `__init__()` method was defined in the class it will be called automatically to initialize the attributes of the object with any arguments that might have been passed in the class call with one additional one at the beginning usually named `self` which a name that can be used to refer to the instance itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I've edited my previous anwser, which was working but as pointed out, not really a good practice)

There is slight confusion between object representation in Python here :

```
test1 = A 
print test1 #return : <class '__main__.A'>
```

In python you can copy a class, because a class in also an object in Python. You can see as an alias, but it is more useful than that.

```
test2 = A() 
print test2 #return : <__main__.A object at 0x0126DF90>
```

Here you have created an A object at a certain adress.

```
print test1().a
```

What you are doing is in reality : `A().a` . In other word you create a temporary object and then call the a property. It works in your example but it is not more useful than a static method since the object is temporary (usually class methods take are used to view/modify an object's internal state).

`print test2().a # == [A()]().a`
This does not work because you want to call an object as a method. To do so you have to add a `__call__` special method in the class description. If your a property is important, that's what I would do :

```
class State(object):
    " Dummy Finite state machine "

    def __init__(self)
         self.count = 0

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self.count % 4

    def __call__(self):
        return self.state

    def next(self):
        self.count +=1

s = State() # State object
print s() # return 0
s.next() # count = 1
s.next() # count = 2
s.next() # count = 3
s.next() # count = 4
s.next() # count = 5
print s() # return 5 % 4 =1
```

Comment: Good to demonstrate `__call__`, but making it return it's own object is ummm, really not good practice

Comment: Please remove the `__call__` thing here, i think it will be more confusing to OP than anything else.

Comment: I've improved my answer, for more clarity